# String Comparison differences between .NET and T-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, comparison

In a test case I've written, the string comparison doesn't appear to work the same way between SQL server / .NET CLR.

This C# code:

```
string lesser =  "SR2-A1-10-90";
string greater = "SR2-A1-100-10";

Debug.WriteLine(string.Compare("A","B"));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Compare(lesser, greater));
```

Will output:

```
-1
1
```

This SQL Server code:

```
declare @lesser varchar(20);
declare @greater varchar(20);

set @lesser =  'SR2-A1-10-90';
set @greater = 'SR2-A1-100-10';

IF @lesser < @greater
    SELECT 'Less Than';
ELSE
    SELECT 'Greater than';
```

Will output:

```
Less Than
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Are you accounting for case-sensitivity?

Comment: The cases are the same.  The difference is how each treats the '0' to '-'.

Comment: This is a Unicode issue I think. Edit: Maybe not. For me the SQL Server code returns `Greater than`. What is the default collation in the database you are testing it on?

Comment: `IF @lesser < @greater collate Latin1_General_CI_AS` gives `greater than`. `IF @lesser < @greater collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` gives `less than` for me too.

Comment: Okay, yeah.  If I manually specify the collation, I get the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [documented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112).

Windows collations (e.g. `Latin1_General_CI_AS`) use Unicode type collation rules. SQL Collations don't.

This causes the hyphen character to be treated differently between the two.

Comment: select * from fn_helpcollations()
where name like '%SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS%'
or name = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'

Comment: The non-unicode sort is different, uses CP 1252. I'm sure LATIN1.. did the same too... no it doesn't.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515.aspx

Comment: Just to add a page for documentation since I got here first afte so many years.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 7):

Further to gbn's answer, you can make them behave the same by using CompareOptions.StringSort in C# (or by using StringComparison.Ordinal). This treats symbols as occurring before alphanumeric symbols, so "-" < "0".

However, Unicode vs ASCII doesn't explain anything, as the hex codes for the ASCII codepage are translated verbatim to the Unicode codepage: "-" is 002D (45) while "0" is 0030 (48).

What is happening is that .NET is using "linguistic" sorting by default, which is based on a non-ordinal ordering and weight applied to various symbols by the specified or current culture. This linguistic algorithm allows, for instance, "résumé" (spelled with accents) to appear immediately following "resume" (spelled without accents) in a sorted list of words, as "é" is given a fractional order just after "e" and well before "f". It also allows "cooperation" and "co-operation" to be placed closely together, as the dash symbol is given low "weight"; it matters only as the absolute final tiebreakers when sorting words like "bits", "bit's", and "bit-shift" (which would appear in that order).

So-called ordinal sorting (strictly according to Unicode values, with or without case insensitivity) will produce very different and sometimes illogical results, as variants of letters usually appear well after the basic undecorated Latin alphabet in ASCII/Unicode ordinals, while symbols occur before it. For instance, "é" comes after "z" and so the words "resume", "rosin", "ruble", "résumé" would be sorted in that order. "Bit's", "Bit-shift", "Biter", "Bits" would be sorted in that order as the apostrophe comes first, followed by the dash, then the letter "e", then the letter "s". Neither of these seem logical from a "natural language" perspective.

Comment: Code page only affects chars > 127, no?

Comment: Cool.  By using the `CompareOption.StringSort`, I can run my test, with the current database collation settings.

Comment: @gbn - Technically yes. It's also C# that seems to be sorting "wrong"; without StringSort, symbols chars come after alphanumerics. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

- In SQL you used varchar which is basically ASCII (subject to collation) which will give - before 0
- In C# all strings are Unicode

The finer points of UTF-xx (c#) vs UCS-2 (SQL Server) are quite tricky.

Edit:

I posted too soon

I get "Greater Than" on SQL Server 2008 with collation Latin1_General_CI_AS

Edit 2:

I'd also try `SELECT ASCII(...)` on your dash. For example, if the SQL snippet has ever been in a Word document the - (150) is not the - (45) I copied into SQL Server for testing out of my browser from your questions. See [CP 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (= CP1 = SQL Server lingo)

Edit 3: See Martin Smith's answer: the 2 collations have different sort orders.

Comment: Ah, I see.  When I use nvarchar(20), I get `Greater Than`.

Comment: I get this with varchar. Is your DB collation different to Server collation?

Answer (score 1):

Several great answers already on why this happens, but I'm sure others just want to know the C# code to iterate the collection in the same order as SQL server. I have found the following works best. "Ordinal" gets around the hyphen issue while "IgnoreCase" seems to reflect the SQL server default as well.

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Compare(lesser, greater, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```