C# sorted get different result from ORDER BY in SQL Server
I need to replicate the exact order produced by another program that used the ORDER BY clause in its SQL query:
SELECT Name 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY Name

Result:

To reproduce the order on my side, I am using C# on .NET 8.0.
Here is the code I used:
var sorted = list.OrderBy(o => o.Name);

Result:

I tried with StringComparer.Ordinal:
var sorted = list.OrderBy(o => o.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal);

Result:

I also tried using other StringComparer options - without success.
Is there any way to achieve the same behavior as T-SQL?

You've tagged this MySQL, but the output table in your screenshot looks to me like what you'd see from SSMS and SQL Server. Is this correct? Also, is list an in-memory collection, or is the LINQ query being translated into SQL by some library?

You are right, its sql server, I will update the title. The List here is a simple 'var list = new List(); just set before.

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808158/1043380

What is the collation in SQL Server?

In ma case: Latin1_General_CI_AI

@user23787413 Do the answers to What .NET StringComparer is equivalent SQL's Latin1_General_CI_AS lead you anywhere useful?

The sorting behavior you are seeing on your C# side is consistent with standard ASCII case sensitive behavior, since C comes before [ which comes before a.  On the SQL side, it appears that a case insensitive collation is being used, and that sorting is happening as if every character had been lowercased.  We know that because there a is sorting before C, implying the latter is sorting as c.
You could try sorting the lowercased character on the C# side:
var sorted = list.OrderBy(o => o.Name.ToLower(), StringComparer.Ordinal);


Already tried, it does not reproduce the same behavior :/ The character '[' will still be behind the number '1'

@user23787413 What is the collation set to on the table? mysql check collation of a table

@AndrewMorton It's Latin1_General_CI_AI

Maybe look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975698/implementing-custom-icomparer-with-string
